# Continuos Footnotes by separate even and odd pages

Tags: footnotes

I have a latin text in odd pages and its translation on even pages. But I need different footnotes for the odd and even pages. Nevertheless, I don't want them to restart in every page: I need them to be continuous separately both even and odd pages'  footnotes.

Thank you.

Comment: what format/packages are you using?

Comment: Off-topic, but I can't help asking: what is the non-Latin language?  Most of the time (in "Western" languages; and in my experience), the Latin appears on the verso, or even, pages.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing a facing page edition and translation, the best packages for this are the twinned `eledmac` and `eledpar`.  Here's an example; but note that this barely scratches the surface of the possibilities. (In particular, I'm not using any of the "critical text/edition" macros.)  If you provide a real details regarding what you are hoping to accomplish (along with a real MWE), you may get a better answer.  (I'm happy to try, anyway.)

```
% Compile twice to resolve footnotes
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{eledmac, eledpar, lipsum}

\begin{document}
% Can't start "parallel" pages on an odd page
% Thus, "page 1" is blank
\begin{pages}

  \begin{Leftside}
  \beginnumbering\pstart
  \footnoteA{One}
  \footnoteA{Two}
  \footnoteA{Three}
  \footnoteA{Four}
  \footnoteA{Five}
  \lipsum
  \pend\endnumbering
  \end{Leftside}

  \begin{Rightside}
  \beginnumbering\pstart
  \footnoteB{One}
  \footnoteB{Two}
  \footnoteB{Three}
  \footnoteB{Four}
  \footnoteB{Five}
  \lipsum
  \pend\endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}

\Pages

  \begin{Leftside}% it might be better to create new environments for these
  \beginnumbering\pstart
  \footnoteA{One}
  \footnoteA{Two}
  \footnoteA{Three}
  \footnoteA{Four}
  \footnoteA{Five}
  \lipsum
  \pend\endnumbering
  \end{Leftside}

  \begin{Rightside}% it might be better to create new environments for these
  \beginnumbering\pstart
  \footnoteB{One}
  \footnoteB{Two}
  \footnoteB{Three}
  \footnoteB{Four}
  \footnoteB{Five}
  \lipsum
  \pend\endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}

\Pages

\end{pages}

\end{document}
```