# How to typeset multilingual adjacently parallel paragraphs within a page with different footnotes

Tags: footnotes, multicolumn, parallel, parcolumns

[image: Devanagari and English]

The above example was created using an WYSIWYG editor.  But want to achieve same using xelatex where different footnotes (explanatory, variants) can also be used. Any pointers.

Comment: Use the pair of packages, `eledmac` and `eledpar`.  Perhaps [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197134/8528) of mine will get you started.

Comment: @jon I am sorry for using wrong wording in question. I meant adjacently parallel paragraphs to be type set.

Comment: I don't quite understand.  The image in your question does not seem to correspond to the phrase 'adjacently parallel paragraphs'..?

Comment: By "parallel" I meant not in respect to even and odd pages but within the Page itself. There are two stories running through each page parallel to themselves.

Comment: Then, no.  You cannot do this without a **major** programming investment (by you or someone else) to implement that style --- which may not really be conducive to a programmatic solution.  (But look at the `flowfram` package.)  But, then again, why must it be in that style?  It is very common to have dual-language books, and the most common format I've seen is to having facing-page translations.  What is the advantage to splitting each page into two variable blocks?

Comment: I will have a look at `flowfram` package. Regarding accommodating source and translation within a page: Due to large cultural and philosophical differences between Sanskrit and English the translations always expand with explanations. So a page of Sanskrit texts translation would run 2 to 3 pages. So in India the splitting the page is common. It is also apparent from the image I have used.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think `flowfram` will be of much use.  In fact, I don't think TeX itself (and its derivatives) is the right tool for this task if you want to have two different output streams (plus footnotes!) to spit out two different and always changing 'boxes' of text.  Packages like `eledpar` torture the output routine quite heavily and I think it is much easier to do that than what you are hoping for.  (I'd love to be proven wrong, of course.)

Comment: This may not be possible but, if it is, you are much more likely to entice people to play around with it and try things out if you provide a Minimal Working Example. Especially since the number of users able to type Sanskrit is likely to be somewhat limited. (Admittedly, I'm making an assumption here but not, I think, an altogether unreasonable one.)

Comment: @jon What about `reledmac` and `reledpar`? There are examples on CTAN of parallel columns with LTR language in one column and RTL language in the other, and it supports various kinds of critical edition things just as the `eledmac`/`eledpar` does. But I thought that even `eledpar` supported parallel texts in columns on the same page. What I don't know is if you can avoid getting blank columns if the translation runs to muliple-pages per page of original text.

Comment: @cfr -- I have yet to try out the brand new `redled*`. (It's on the "for fun" list right now, but that list is off-limits these days.) I suspect the answer will still be "no" since it is a totally foreign setup to the "Western" world of facing-page edition/translations, and surely at least an order of magnitude more difficult ([i] two blocks in parallel, [ii] across two pages, [iii] unevenly taking up varying amounts of space, *and with* [iv] their own dedicated footnote streams)!  If I could implement that, I'd print up a t-shirt to that effect and wear it at least once a week!

Comment: (con't @cfr) In fact, I'd like to implement [this kind](http://daten.digitale-sammlungen.de/bsb00036987/image_51) of two separate input stream page layout for a translation I've been contemplating, and I think this would be far, far easier to do.  But still not easy! (That's just a random example, but you get the idea.)

Comment: @jon Probably I just don't understand this question.

Comment: @cfr -- I'm not sure I fully do either, but note how the 3,4,5 sequence appears in the two different streams. How on earth is TeX supposed to figure out where to break from Sanskrit page1 to Sanskrit page2 *and* English page1 to English page2 *and* save space for two sets of footnotes?? The goal is to avoid lots of empty whitespace since the English text is much longer than the Sanskrit. It seems impossible to me (... because it is impossible *for* me).

Answer (score 1):

If your output is limited to single pages, you could use minipages. Each minipage has its own footnotes, though the numbering will be alphabetical in both.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{1\columnwidth}
    Some text.\footnote{An explanatory note.}
\end{minipage}

\newpage{}

\begin{minipage}[t]{1\columnwidth}
    Some text in another column.\footnote{Another footnote}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi penguinpreferred. Could you please extend your answer? On the site we try to encourage users to provide detailed answers, preferably in form of minimal working examples useful to test the effectiveness of the solution. As it stands, your answer appears to be a comment.

Comment: I am working on a book.

Comment: Expansion provided. Thanks for the heads-up. Unfortunately, it does not work for multiple pages.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at `bigfoot` which provides footnotes to footnotes. I guess you could just consider your translation as a big set of notes and attach them section by section to the beginning of the original text-chunks. Both original and translation could in turn have each their own (or even several) note-systems for annotations.

Try my rough sketch below. If you think this could work for you, `bigfoot` has a lot of options to fine-tune the setup of the notes. Unfortunately its documentation is difficult to read, as many of its features are only described as a running commentary to the code. Much of the syntax is identical to `manyfoot` though, so you could have a look at its documentation, too.

I haven't even tried to come up with automatic processing of the devanāgarī and Western-style numbers for the sections. Perhaps this is even the most practical way in the long run, as sectioning in historical texts (at least the ones I've seen) tends to be irregular anyway.

Compile with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Arial Unicode MS}


\usepackage[ruled]{bigfoot}

%change order for placement:
\DeclareNewFootnote{C}[alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}

%unnumbered notes only for A:
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{}

\begin{document}

३.\footnoteA{3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi commodo, ipsum sed pharetra gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit amet\footnoteB{A comment to the translation.} enim. Suspendisse id velit vitae ligula volutpat condimentum. Aliquam erat\footnoteB{Another comment} volutpat. Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper, lectus nunc ullamcorper orci, fermentum bibendum enim nibh eget ipsum. Donec porttitor ligula eu dolor. Maecenas vitae nulla consequat libero cursus venenatis. Nam magna enim, accumsan eu, blandit sed, blandit a, eros.} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi commodo, ipsum sed pharetra gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit amet enim. Suspendisse id velit vitae ligula volutpat\footnoteC{A comment to the main text if needed.} condimentum.

४.\footnoteA{4. Quisque facilisis erat a dui. Nam malesuada ornare dolor. Cras gravida, diam sit amet rhoncus ornare, erat elit consectetuer erat, id egestas pede\footnoteB{Another comment} nibh eget odio. Proin tincidunt, velit vel porta elementum, magna diam molestie sapien, non aliquet massa pede eu diam. Aliquam iaculis. Fusce et ipsum et nulla tristique facilisis. Donec eget sem sit amet ligula viverra gravida. Etiam\footnoteB{Another comment} vehicula urna vel turpis. Nunc molestie, nisl sit amet cursus convallis, sapien lectus pretium metus, vitae pretium\footnoteB{Another comment} enim wisi id lectus.\footnoteB{Another comment} Donec vestibulum. Etiam vel nibh. Nulla facilisi. Mauris pharetra. Donec augue. Fusce ultrices, neque id dignissim ultrices, tellus mauris dictum elit, vel lacinia enim metus eu nunc.} Quisque facilisis erat a dui. Nam malesuada ornare dolor. Cras gravida, diam sit amet rhoncus ornare, erat elit consectetuer erat, id egestas pede nibh eget odio. Proin tincidunt, velit vel porta elementum, magna diam molestie sapien, non aliquet massa pede eu diam. Aliquam iaculis. Fusce et ipsum et nulla tristique facilisis. Donec eget sem sit amet ligula viverra gravida. Etiam vehicula urna vel turpis. Suspendisse\footnoteC{Another comment} sagittis ante a urna. 

\pagebreak
\section*{Heading}
\footnoteA{\par\noindent{\large Chapterheading}\par}%
\indent५.\footnoteA{5. Proin at eros non eros adipiscing mollis. Donec semper turpis sed diam. Sed consequat ligula nec tortor. Integer eget sem. Ut vitae enim eu est vehicula\footnoteB{Another comment} gravida. Morbi ipsum ipsum, porta nec, tempor id, auctor vitae, purus. Pellentesque neque. Nulla luctus erat vitae libero. Integer nec enim. Phasellus aliquam enim et tortor. Quisque aliquet, quam elementum condimentum feugiat, tellus\footnoteB{Another comment} odio consectetuer wisi, vel nonummy sem neque in elit. Curabitur eleifend wisi iaculis ipsum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In non velit non ligula laoreet ultrices. Praesent ultricies facilisis nisl. Vivamus luctus elit sit amet mi. Phasellus pellentesque, erat eget elementum volutpat, dolor nisl porta neque, vitae sodales ipsum nibh in ligula. Maecenas mattis pulvinar diam. Curabitur sed leo.\footnoteB{Another comment}} Proin at eros non eros adipiscing mollis. Donec semper turpis sed diam. Sed consequat ligula nec tortor. Integer eget sem. Ut vitae enim eu est vehicula gravida. Morbi ipsum ipsum, porta nec, tempor id, auctor vitae, purus. Pellentesque neque. Nulla luctus erat vitae libero. Integer nec enim. Phasellus aliquam enim et tortor. Quisque aliquet, quam elementum condimentum feugiat, tellus odio consectetuer wisi, vel nonummy sem neque in elit. Maecenas mattis pulvinar diam. Curabitur sed leo.

६.\footnoteA{6. Nulla facilisi. In vel sem. Morbi id urna in diam dignissim feugiat. Proin molestie tortor eu velit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam ultrices, diam tempus vulputate egestas, eros pede varius leo, sed imperdiet lectus est ornare odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Proin consectetuer velit in dui. Phasellus wisi purus, interdum vitae, rutrum accumsan, viverra in, velit. Sed enim risus, congue non, tristique in, commodo eu, metus. Aenean tortor mi, imperdiet id, gravida eu, posuere eu, felis. Mauris sollicitudin, turpis in hendrerit sodales, lectus ipsum pellentesque ligula, sit amet scelerisque urna nibh ut arcu. Aliquam in lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla placerat aliquam wisi. Mauris viverra odio. Quisque fermentum pulvinar odio. Proin posuere est vitae ligula. Etiam euismod. Cras a eros.} Nulla facilisi. In vel sem. Morbi id urna in diam dignissim feugiat. Proin molestie tortor eu velit. 

७.\footnoteA{7. Nunc auctor bibendum eros. Maecenas porta accumsan mauris. Etiam enim enim, elementum sed, bibendum quis, rhoncus non, metus. Fusce neque dolor, adipiscing sed, consectetuer et, lacinia sit amet, quam. Suspendisse wisi quam, consectetuer in, blandit sed, suscipit eu, eros.} Nunc auctor bibendum eros. Maecenas porta accumsan mauris. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reledmac package works good for it. You have to attach your translation as either critical footnotes or familiar footnotes. Reledmac will adjust the flow of translation and can adjust bigger footnotes which may run to next page.

However, if your comments are very very long and related to nearby words, then it may leave some white space.

But, in your case it may not occur, since you can attatc the whole translation to the last word of mUlam(original) as footnote.

Just use`\usepackage[parapparatus]{reledmac}` in preamble and use `\edtext{the original text}{\Afootnote{Footnotes go here.}}` this in document.[image: A sample from my work.]

In the example file attached I've use some other tricks to get line numbers and the line splitting original and commentary.

To hide footmark numbers `\Xnonumber` `\Xendnonumber`.

`\linenummargin{inner}` to set the place to print line number.

To adjust line number start and line number increment `\firstlinenum{1}` `\linenumincrement{1}`.

To change critical footnote size `\Xnotefontsize[A]{\large}`
and to change familiar footnote size `\notefontsizeX[A]{\large}`.

To separated multiple footnotes `\providecommand*{\multfootsep}{\textsuperscript{\normalfont,}}`.

To print divider horizontal line for familiar footnotes `\renewcommand\footnoteruleA{ %
    \kern-3pt \hrule width 4in \kern 2.6pt
}%%Adjust it according to your need.`

And for critical footnotes 
`\renewcommand\Afootnoterule{ %
    \kern-3pt \hrule width 4in \kern 2.6pt
}%%Adjust it according to your need.`

Customize lemma separator 
`\Xlemmaseparator[A]{==>}`.

Use other packages to adjust parindent, etc.